# Override ~ behaviour in controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting, relative-path

Quick backstory: I'm making a "framed" version of my site that has a different master page than normal (one suitable for iframing). It's accessed by `mysite.com/Framed/whatever`, instead of `mysite.com/whatever`. This is rewritten in IIS to `mysite.com/whatever?framed=true`. That works fine.

The issue I'm having is that all the links are relative using a ~ like `~/Server.aspx` which works fine in the normal site. I need to override that so instead of producing `../Server.aspx` (as it "should") it produces `../Framed/Server.aspx` or `Server.aspx`.

Currently this means that the page goes back to it's normal view (`mystite.com/whatever2`) as soon as you click on a link, I want it to continue to stay in `mysite.com/Framed/...`

Answer (score 0):

Don't you really want "../Server.aspx?framed=true" ? That might be easier to pull off

Comment: That would be easier, but I'm still not sure about it.

Also: I got the behavior I wanted with some simple javascript that rewrote the page if it was in a frame.

Answer (score 0):

~ resolves to the root of the application, so you could create a virtual directory beneath your main site for your framed version called "Framed", so "~/" resolves to "/Framed/". Then instead of using a query string switch to select your master page, you can check for the presence of "/Framed/" in the raw request URI.